# javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress UTF-8 in local-part

Tags: java, email, utf-8, jakarta-mail

I'm searching for a solution to send a mail to UTF-8 encoded mail-addresses. The domain-part is no problem, because I can encode it using punycode and send it then.

But how do I handle the local-part of a mail-address? For example I want to send a mail to müller@testdomain.com? `javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress` says, that this is not a valid address.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Javamail does not support SMTPUTF8: https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javamail does not support SMTPUTF8 (as defined in [RFC6531, local part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531#section-3.2)), shown by the still open [Bugreport](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6216). A quick search did not bring up another supporting Java library. Apache Commons Email e.g. also depends on Javamail.

**Update:** JavaMail 1.6.0 [which now supports internationalized email addresses (RFC 6530/6531/6532)](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/releases/tag/JAVAMAIL-1_6_0) is released since July 2017. Apache Commons Email 1.5 (August 2017) [unfortunately still depends on JavaMail 1.5.6](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/changes-report.html#a1.5).

Comment: If you're interested in testing a version of JavaMail 1.6.0 with this support, please contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Comment: @BillShannon I sent an email to javamail_ww@oracle.com, but received a bounce notification. I'm interested in when JavaMail 1.6 will be released and in testing the change.

Comment: A bounce?  Really?  Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried if URL encoding works? So it would become: `m%C3%BCller@testdomain.com`.